# Null property when fetching an entity with its empty associations through join DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm

When I'm using DQL with joins to get an entity with its TO_MANY associations and if there's no element linked to the entity through associations, the entity related properties are populated with NULL instead of empty ArrayCollections (actually, they are not populated at all and stays with default class properties, since no constructor nor method is called) . Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Example :

DQL :

```
SELECT node, ownerLink, node_linkedEntity1, node_linkedEntity1_ownerLink, node_linkedEntity2, node_linkedEntity3 FROM MyNamespace\MyObject node LEFT JOIN node.ownerLink ownerLink LEFT JOIN node.entities1 node_linkedEntity1 LEFT JOIN node_linkedEntity1.ownerLink node_linkedEntity1_ownerLink LEFT JOIN node.entity2 node_linkedEntity2 LEFT JOIN node.entities3 node_linkedEntity3 WHERE node.root=:root_id AND node.id<>:root_id ORDER BY node.lft ASC
```

Mapping :

```yaml
MyNamespace\MyObject:
    type: entity
    table: objects
    gedmo:
        tree:
            type: nested
    id:
        id:
            type: smallint
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
            id: true
            column: id
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        lft:
            type: integer
            options:
                unsigned: true
            gedmo:
                - treeLeft
        rgt:
            type: integer
            options:
                unsigned: true
            gedmo:
                - treeRight
        root:
            type: smallint
            options:
                unsigned: true
            nullable: true
            gedmo:
                - treeRoot
        lvl:
            type: smallint
            options:
                unsigned: true
            gedmo:
                - treeLevel
        -- anyOtherField
    oneToOne:
        ownerLink:
            targetEntity: MyNamespace\OwnerLink
            mappedBy: object
            fetch: EAGER
            cascade:
                - persist
        entity2:
            targetEntity: MyNamespace\Entity2
            cascade: 
                - persist
            fetch: LAZY
            joinColumns:
                entity2_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: MyNamespace\MyObject
            inversedBy: children
            joinColumn:
                name: parent_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
            cascade: [persist]
            gedmo:
                - treeParent

    oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: MyNamespace\MyObject
            mappedBy: parent
            cascade: [persist]
            orderBy:
                lft: ASC
    manyToMany:
        entities1:
            targetEntity: MyNamespace\Entity1
            mappedBy: object
            fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
            joinTable:
                name: object_entity1
                joinColumns:
                    id:
                        referencedColumnName: object_id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    entity1_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
        entities3:
            targetEntity: MyNamepace\Entity3
            fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
            joinTable:
                name: object_entity3
                joinColumns:
                    id:
                        referencedColumnName: object_id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    entity3_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

What's going on is that, at entity creation time, since associations are fetched from the query result, the null values corresponding to empty join results are passed as is to reflection field setValue method, and that's all (fetchAlias fields are ignored after that). If I don't fetch the associations (by removing theme from the select statement), the TO_MANY associations are correctly initiated to empty collections.

Comment: Do you add your entity to select? Can you post your query example?

Comment: I'll update with some example but yes, I select the associated entities if any (I think it's called fetch join or fetched alias in doc)

Comment: For now, the only thing I could do to fix this strange behavior would be to change all the domain methods that retrieve collections to check if the collection was correctly initialized.